How is this question not focused? Questions are being closed prematurely
Question Link: Is this argument roughly analogous to the fine tuning argument?
There’s only one question here and the person that commented about it not being focused in the comments (Lowri) deleted her comments after I edited it to be smaller
Similar situation with the question I posted here where the commenter also points out it makes no sense for it to be closed (consciousness being an abstract object): Could consciousness be a special kind of abstract object?

Yes, it is focused enough. You are not asking two questions. I suspect some of the close voters just didn't understand how your question about the cards relates to the fine tuning argument, and thought they were two totally separate things you were asking. Get 4 reopen votes and let me know and I will be the 5th.

@causative I don’t think it has anything to do with that and to be honest, I seem to be targeted now. Here’s another example of a question that was upvoted and another commenter agreed it’s reasonable to stay open: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/119290/how-do-we-differentiate-pure-lunacy-from-just-a-different-opinion-in-philosoph?noredirect=1#comment376780_119290

In general, any question on ID can probably be closed as duplicate of previous questions. It's not a complex topic, and all likely that can be asked about it has already been asked. Closing for other reasons happens because it's quicker than finding a good duplicate. Consider doing research first.

@tkruse you can apply that reasoning to many questions on the site. Many questions are variants of general questions that have already been asked, ID or not. But with other topics, they are rarely closed.

There is no necessary consistency, other factors come into play like the goodwill of the readers, which wears thin if an asker keeps asking low value questions in a short timeframe as an example.

A question being closed can be a precedent for other questions to be closed. But a question left open does not mean other questions should equally be left open. Rather often the older question should equally be closed.

Also yes, there are other topics with more questions than makes sense, free will and the trolley problem as examples. Hard to imagine a new question can be asked that has no duplicate

You’re ignoring the role of the potential bad faith of readers and viewers @tkruse this is not a one way road. Anyways, as pointed out by the other mod, and multiple re open votes, the question should not have been closed

If anyone wants to assume bad faith of readers/answerers, they should not ask here, but somewhere else where they expect more goos faith.

@tkruse -- So you admit to violating the site code of conduct, closing questions for invalid reasons, and do so as an effort to harass other posters who have annoyed you by asking questions on topics you dislike seeing on the site.   You also are too lazy to actually find "duplicates" that could point the asker to a useful answer to their question, and use your laziness to rationalize the invalid closure. Noted.  Yes, good faith is not in evidence in your behavior, but IS called for in our code of conduct, and is required for an SE to operate as intended.

@causative  both OP questions are at four reopen votes.

@Dcleve OK, I have voted to reopen both. I do it this way because otherwise my vote would reopen the question unilaterally and I don't think it would be fair to overturn a majority even though I don't agree with that majority's decision.
